# Querying form to SQL error

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to make a textarea to submit and query into datbase. Now I have a couple of different elements in my query, I also have a image dropbox that gives me image URL's in a session. Once I hit the submit button I want to query and INSERT all this information into my database. Now, I can hit submit and it reloads the page, however, nothing is submitted to my database... am I missing the obvious?

```
else if ($_GET['page'] === strval(2)){

            if (isset($_POST['postbutton'])){
                $articlepost = ($_POST['article']);
                $pictureurls = "<br>".$_SESSION['urlpost'];
                $thumbnail = 123;
                $title = "HEY THERE";
                $articlepostimg = $articlepost.$pictureurls;

                $insertpost = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (title,post,date_add,thumbnail) VALUES (:title,:post,:date_add,:thumbnail)");
                $insertpost->execute(array(':title' => $title, ':post' => $articlepostimg, ':date_add' => $date_add, ':thumbnail' => $thumbnail));

            }
            else {
                echo '<form method="POST" action="">';
                echo '<textarea autofocus name="article" placeholder="Write your text here..." id="textareaarticle"></textarea>';

                echo '<div id="dropbox">';
                echo '<span class="message">Drop images here to upload.</span>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>';
                echo '<script src="assets/js/jquery.filedrop.js"></script>';
                echo '<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>';
                echo '<input type="submit" name="postbutton" value="Submit" /></form>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: `$date_add` is not defined. Least, not in your posted code. That alone will prevent your INSERT to work.

Comment: Hmmm, wouldn't it just stay blank if its not defined?

Comment: I tend to think not, unless you have a column as `DATETIME` but I'm sceptical about that. Can you try it without it? Or define it as `$date_add = time();` or something to that effect.

Comment: You where right, I think it was the date :) working now! I'f you'd like to post the answer I will accept it

Comment: (off topic but) why are you doing ($_GET['page'] === strval(2)) ? you're using a function to convert a number to string, you're comparing strings and you're using === when you know both are strings. Better suggestion (and safer): ((int)$_GET['page'] == 2)

Comment: Glad it worked out @FriedBitz it's posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$date_add` variable is not defined. Least, not in your posted code.

That alone will prevent your `INSERT` to work, unless you define it.